# Is it possible to format text in R in the same way as python?

Tags: r, formatting, string-formatting

I was wondering if it is possible to do text parsing in R in the same way as python does it.

So python does it like this:

```
"Hello World! I am from {country}".format("The Netherlands")
```

Now i am looking for the exact same thing in R, or something which works in the same way.

I was thinking of using `gsub` or something like that. But that does not feel right. Maybe `sprintf` or `format` function is what i need.

Off course it is not difficult to find the proper solution but i was just wondering if there is something like python formatting in R.

Comment: You won't be able to reproduce Python-style formatting exactly because R does not treat `.` as the member access operator, but [this article](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GetoptLong/vignettes/variable_interpolation.html) may be useful to you.

Comment: @nrussell that was what i was expecting indeed. Thanks for the article will be useful.

Comment: something like `sprintf("Hello World! I am from %s", "The Netherlands")` what you're looking for?

Comment: @dww, yes indeed something like that. Will look more into sprintf function,. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to `sprintf` (mentionned in a comment), you can use the `glue` package:

```
library(glue)

country <- "The Netherlands"
glue("Hello I am from {country}.")

# or
glue("Hello I am from {country}.", country = "Germany")
```